# How do we open an external link from a Phone Gap iPhone application in a new window?

Tags: cordova

I'm trying to launch an external link using phone gap with that code, but it just raises the alert, and after that nothing happens! :-(

```
$("#externalLink", $(this)).click(function(){
    alert('I´m here!');
    window.location.href('http://www.wordreference.com');
});
```

I also tried to use a direct "" link directly in the HTML code, but it also does not work :(

Any idea?

Comment: Are you using anything like jQuery Mobile with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now it very easy: 
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.5.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#InAppBrowser
for details.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the childbrowser plugin here: https://github.com/purplecabbage/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iPhone/ChildBrowser

it lets you open external pages in a seperate browser window.